# How to validate soap webservice request parameters for XSS attcaks in java

Tags: java, security, soap, xss, soap-client

how do i secure my api from Client site scripting attcaks or XSS attcaks?

we have a soap endpoint which is accessed by many clients and the incoming request data is to be validated for the correctness and security.

there is a chance that incoming request may have DOM object model or any suspicious data that breaks the application.

like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="http://www.abcxyz.com/aaa/bbb" xmlns:ws="http://www.abcxyz.com/aaa/bbb">
   <soapenv:Header>
      **<cus:id>
         <SCRIPT>a=/XSS/alert(a.source)</SCRIPT>
      </cus:id>**
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cus:cancelRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ws:transactionId>10000</ws:transactionId>
         <ws:systemId>CCC</ws:systemId>
         <ws:userId>USER_NAME</ws:userId>
         <cus:cancelElements>
            <cus:elementType>NAME</cus:elementType>
            <cus:elementId>AB123</cus:elementId>
         </cus:cancelElements>
      </cus:cancelRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

if there is any attacks from a hacker by passing maliciouse data as part of request parameters then i need to handle it and thro an error or don't allow the data to get processed.

Comment: Hi, can you mark the answers if its been useful for you or not. Please appreciate ppl have taken time to respond to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is ,you have to write an XSD(schema Definitions) file and this XSD should be able to validate against the element in  above mentioned xml file.

Answer: You have to import a package **import javax.xml.*;** . In that you will be able to validate your xml file against you xsd .

For example : Employee.xsd
              EployeeRequest.xml

```
Employee.xsd

<simpleType name="Imei">
<annotation>
<documentation>A string representing the IMEI number. An IMEI will be of 15 digit.</documentation>
</annotation>
<restriction base="string">
<pattern value="\d{15}"/>
</restriction>
```

```
validateXMLSchema("Employee.xsd", "EmployeeRequest.xml"));
```

For reference click [here](https://www.journaldev.com/895/how-to-validate-xml-against-xsd-in-java).

Comment: how can i do this if i have only one xsd file with different complextType elements defined for xml files?
basically if 10 or more xml files are there, all the optional data is processed inside the single xsd file. 
then it is not feasible to validate like above?
please let me know if any other ways to do this, correct me of i am wrong

Comment: I believe that u need to write different xsd file for each and every xml file. I guess that is the Standard.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use an Encode method in Java to solve this. I am sure Java has an Encode method or something of that sort.